# I'd like to click on data in one cell and be transferred to another sheet that contains that initial cell data but with a different dataset?

Tags: excel

Situation: Excel book with 3 sheets. First sheet is ProductSummary. 2nd: BatchSummary. 3rd BatchDetail.

ProductSummary has general product data that is common in the other sheets. Column C in ProductSummary is titled ProductMaterialCode.

We'd like to be able to click on a cell in Column C, and after clicking we are transferred to the 2nd sheet (BatchSummary). On this sheet, we will see all columns that relate to the date point that was clicked on in Column C. Column C on both sheets are both ProductMaterialCode. A similar process will occur in the 2nd sheet to get to the 3rd sheet.

I assume that I want to use hyperlinks, but I don't understand how to get them to work for this project.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're asking us to guess because you've given us nothing to work with other than a vague description of what you want. How are we supposed to know what 'columns related to that data point' actually means? In any case, it sounds like you can take the macro approach.

Comment: Nobody is going to write all the code for you but you should have a look at how to create an onclick function on a sheet then how to get the reference of the cell that was clicked so that you can use that to determine what the code will do next.  I doesn't sound like you'll be able to do what you want with a hyperlink so you'll need to write some VBA code.  Once you have some code then you can post it here if you still need help.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity of the request, it was an ambiguous question that was asked of me and neither of us were sure how to directly go about it and its even harder trying to describe something someone else They have no idea what they want, so its just a confusing mess. I'll try better next time. Thank you Mr. Gordon, I will relay your suggestion.